# How do I combine TimeoutError and tqdm progress bar in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, timeout, python-multiprocessing, tqdm

I would like to perform multiprocessing using BOTH TimeoutError and tqdm progress bar.

I have been successful at trying them separately.  How should I combine the logic?

Goals:

- The progress bar should update with every imap_unordered call
- Every process should be checked for TimeoutError

I've tried a million ways to combine them (not shown).  Every time I wrap the imap_unordered call with tqdm, then I am not able to access the "res.next" method for timeout.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError
from tqdm import tqdm

def runner(obj):
    obj.go()
    return obj

def dispatch(objs):

    with Pool() as pool:
        newObjs = list(tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(runner, objs), total=len(objs)))

    # need to find a way to integrate TimeoutError into progress bar
    # I've tried this a million ways using multiprocessing

    # try:
    #     res.next(timeout=10)
    # except TimeoutError:
    #     raise

    return newObjs
```

Code works perfectly for progress bar.  Need to track if any process exceeds timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the progress bar without an iterator and update it manually using [`update()`](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/#update).

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError as mpTimeoutError
from tqdm import tqdm


def runner(obj):
    obj.go()
    return obj


def dispatch(objs):
    with Pool() as pool:
        it = pool.imap_unordered(runner, objs)
        pbar = tqdm(total=len(objs))
        new_objs = []

        while True:
            try:
                new_objs.append(it.next(timeout=10))
                pbar.update()

            except mpTimeoutError:
                raise

            except StopIteration:
                # signal that the iterator is exhausted
                pbar.close()
                break

    return new_objs
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve the desired behavior using the [parallelbar](https://dubovikmaster.github.io/parallelbar/#installation) library. Example:

```py
from parallelbar import progress_imapu

def runner(obj):
    obj.go()
    return obj

if __name__=='__main__':
    result = progress_imapu(runner, objs, process_timeout=10)
```